# Calculate running total for each field within a group - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, cumulative-sum

I'm new in MongoDB and I'm trying to update a field with the running total. I have the following structure:

```
...
{
_id: [field id],
oilFieldId: [the id I'm using which represents an oil field id],
tef:[a number],
agg:[the field I'd like to update (currently = "")],
date: [year-month-day]
}
....more records
```

What I'd like to achieve is the update of the 'agg' field that should contain the running total of the 'tef' field. That is, for the first record 'agg' would be the same as 'tef', for the second record 'agg' should be current 'tef' plus previous 'tef' (previous month). All records should be grouped by 'oilFieldId' and should correspond to a specified year.

I don't know if this can be done with aggregation

PS: Desired Output

```
    {
        _id: [field id],
        oilFieldId: "id number",
        tef:[a number],
        agg:tef,
        date: [2018-01-30]
    }
    {
        _id: [field id],
        oilFieldId: "id number",
        tef:[a number],
        agg:tef + [previous tef],
        date: [2018-02-28]
    }
    {
        _id: [field id],
        oilFieldId: "id number",
        tef:[a number],
        agg:tef+[previous tef]+[previous tef],
        date: [2018-03-30]
    }
    {
        _id: [field id],
        oilFieldId: "id number",
        tef:[a number],
        agg:tef+[previous tef]+[previous tef]+[previous tef],
        date: [2018-04-30]
    }
```

Comment: "... for the first record 'agg' would be the same as 'tef'...": How do you determine what is the first record? You mean by the order they exist in the collection _or_ by some other criteria?

Comment: The records should be grouped by oilFieldId and ordered by date within a year (ascending). The first record from my point of view is the first in a group.